# Finding focus and equation of directrix for parabola touches x axis at $(3,0)$ and y axis at $(0,4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Finding focus and equation of directrix for parabola touches x axis at $(3,0)$ and y axis at $(0,4)$.

What I have done here: Equation of line which passes through the point $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$ is $ \frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{4}=1$.

and  slope of above line is $\displaystyle -\frac{4}{3}$

And slope of line about which parabola symmetrical and passes through origin is $\frac{3}{4}$ and equation of that line is $ y=\frac{3x}{4}$.

And from diagram directrix it passes through origin and parallel to line joining $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$ is $ y=-\frac{4x}{3}$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6pL2.jpg)

But I did not understand how do I find focus coordinates?

Comment: I think the formula for the focus coordinates is helpful here:
$$4p(y - k) = (x - h)^2$$
where (h,k) is the vertex of the parabola, and p is the difference between the y-value of the focus and the y-value of the vertex (the x-value of the focus coordinate is the same as that of the vertex)

Comment: Why the downvote? The downvote does not make sense here. Except for the image not correctly added, everything else is correct in the way the post is presented.

Comment: The comments after [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4594465) applies and the equation is $(25/16)*((x-48/25)^2+(y-36/25)^2-((4*y)/5+(3*x)/5)^2)=0.$

Comment: The focus lies on the contact chord. The line from $(0,0)$ to the midpoint of the contact chord is parallel to the axis. Point $(0,0)$ lies on the directrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrect in assuming that the line of symmetry of the parabola is perpendicular to the chord joining $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$. So your equation of the directrix is not correct.

Since the tangents at these points are perpendicular and meet at the origin, these points are the endpoints of a focal chord and the focus lies on this focal chord. Since the tangents at the endpoints of a focal chord must meet on the directrix, the origin lies on the directrix (as you observe).

So here’s a hint:

Assume the directrix has equation $y+kx=0$ with $k>0$, and use the focus-directrix property to establish the value of $k$: namely, the sum of the two perpendicular distances from the points $(3,0)$ and $(0,4)$ to the directrix must equal the distance between these two points (i.e. $5$). Once you have $k$ you will be able to find the coordinates of the focus by considering that it divides the focal chord in the ratio of these two distances.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David Quinn but I am still unable to find focus of that conic. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Have you found the value of $k$?

Comment: Thanks David Quinn got it.

Comment: You are welcome